# How to provide SerializerMethodField input from view.py in django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django DRF, and having difficulty in applying SerializerMethodField (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Following is a simple case of typical model, serializer code, which works perfectly.

serializer.py (before)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py (before)

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def GetAllUsers(request):
    Users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(Users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

In order to deliver additional information which is not included in the model, I changed serializer

serializer.py (after)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

Now I have to find a way to give obj(which has date_joined inside) to serializer, and I think I have to do it in view.py

But I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: `obj` is the instance of the model and it is passed by the serializer to the method. What do you want to do exactly? Is the `obj` you speak of not the `User` instance whose `date_joined` you want to use?

Comment: To me this seems valid, could you include a traceback or description of what is not going as expected?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat My understanding is that obj is not the instance of the model.  It is simply a variable given to the serializer.   Here I don't know how to use get_days_since_joined(obj) and UserSerializer from view.py

Comment: @DavidLouda   Sorry there is no traceback.  Because I don't know how to write view.py file to call get_days_since_joined.

Comment: @JeehoonPark did you try running this. It would work properly, if there is something else you are trying and want to do you should add that to your question. (Note: you don't need to call `get_days_since_joined` that would be done by the serializer)

Comment: try to explicitly include it in fields option in Meta like eg: 
`fields = (
"email",
"username",
"days_since_joined "
)`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass extra context to serializer like this

view.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def GetAllUsers(request):
    Users = User.objects.all()
    context = {"extra_obj": extra_obj}
    serializer = UserSerializer(Users, many=True, context=context)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        extra_obj = self.context.get("extra_obj")
        return (now() - extra_obj.date_joined).days
```

reference the official document [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to include SerializerMethodField name and other model fields which you want to return to api.

There is no need to change views.py, you just have to change serializer.py.

In your case serializer.py will be like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'days_since_joined',
        ]


    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```